# confused about ngRx way to update store

Tags: ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

let's assume I have an array `sortedNums` in store. It is always kept sorted.

```
sortedNums = [1,3,5,6,7,9];
```

Now I got a new number `8` from the server. I want to insert + sort sortedNums.
I have following options:

1. *Doing it in the `reducers` itself*. I can do that but for complex processing, I think `reducers` won't be the right place.
2. *Doing it in a service method and calling it in `reducers`.* Will work but reducers won't stay pure.
3. *Doing it in `effect`*. We don't have access to `sortNums` here. So I need to inject store and subscribe to it. This seems like an overkill to me.

So my question is: what is the `ngRx` way to do store updation which requires access to existing store data.